# How do I make it impossible for a Windows machine to delete a directory (not its contents) on a Linux Samba server?

Tags: linux, permissions, samba, server-message-block

The title says it all. (One of the rare occasions where it actually fits. :P)

Comment: Windows machines don't delete files and folders. Windows users do.

Comment: That is *technically* correct, yes :P... but the machine is still what is performing the action, and I want to block the machine (= user) from doing so. So...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An old trick on the Linux end might work here:

```
mkdir StayingAlive
sudo touch StayingAlive/.CantTouchThis
sudo chattr +i StayingAlive/.CantTouchThis
```

The key here is the immutable attribute on `.CantTouchThis` (you'll probably want a more serious name, like `.rootfile`).  This attribute prevents the file from being deleted (or even modified)--even root cannot delete this without first removing the attribute.  This file will prevent the directory from being emptied, and therefore prevents it from being deleted.

When I've done this in the past I've typically also changed the ownership of the folder and given the user access via the setgid bit (g+s)--although the reasoning behind this escapes me at the moment

```
sudo chown root.user StayingAlive
sudo chmod g+sw StayingAlive
```

Comment: That...that technique was actually tested and found not to work. Maybe it was implemented wrong *tries again*

Comment: Updated... setting the immutable attribute on the file gets this working (technically the immutable file doesn't need to be root-owned, but it provides a little hint the user can't touch it).  I'll mess around a little more as I don't recall having to do this before, but it's been quite a while.

Comment: It's also worth looking into ACL's (via the `setfacl` command)--there's probably a solution there as well

Comment: **The `chattr` command was what did it! Thanks heaps! :D** (Also, the directory names FTW xD)

Answer (score 0):

In order to delete a directory, it must be empty, and you must have write permissions on its parent.

So you can either prevent the directory from getting empty like STW suggested, or you can ensure the user does not have write permissions on the parent of the directory, which they are not allowed to delete.

If you have a directory named `/foo/bar` and a file named `/foo/bar/file`, a user with write permissions on `/foo/bar` can delete the file. But write permissions on `/foo/bar` does not mean permissions to delete `/foo/bar`, deleting would require write permissions on `/foo`.